Split GIFs/APNGs/Animated WEBPs by File Size
How do I split GIFs/APNGs/Animated WEBPs by file size? For example, I have a 200MB gif and I want to split it into 25MB ones.

Yes, I want to split large animations into shorter ones.

You can open it in any video program that supports the file type that you're interested in cutting that allows you to cut. Then cut it. I'm not sure what the real question is

By the way, several smaller videos with the same content are going to be larger in total file size than the 1 larger video due to the way that modern video formats optimize content between frames and the additional metadata overhead
